# scheme getting the last element in a list

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, cdr

Im very new to scheme and the ideas of car, cdr, etc. I have this function to return the last element of a list, but right now it just returns an empty list.

```
 (define (last mylist)
      (if (list? mylist)
              (if (null? mylist)
                  (if (null? (cdr mylist))
                      '()
                      (last (cdr mylist)) 
                   )
              )        
      )
)
```

Comment: i fixed it, now i get nothing

Comment: In the innermost `if` expression, if `(null? (cdr mylist))` is true, you should returns `(car mylist)` instead of an empty list `'()`.

Answer (score 2):

The book [How To Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/) helps you answer this problem by giving you a specific and detailed design recipe. This particular problem is covered in section 9.2, "Non-empty Lists". Broadly, here are the steps you need to follow:

- formulate a data definition for non-empty lists (or take it from the book)
- write the purpose statement, signature, and header for your function
- WRITE TEST CASES (your test cases are going to help a *lot* here. (keep in mind that you don't need to test inputs that aren't allowed by your data definition)
- add the template associated with your data definition (also appears in the book)
- fill in the blank places in the template to complete your definition
- debug.

Answer (score 2):

By your indentation alone, it's very evident that you're coming to Scheme from another programming language

But you're also using `if` incorrectly – in Scheme, you cannot have a *single-branch* `if` statement. Well, there's no *statements* in Scheme at all, only *expressions*, and `if` expressions will always take 3 operands (arguments)

1. the *predicate* (condition)
2. the *consequent* (what happens if the predicate is true)
3. the *alternative* (what happens when the predicate is false)

Your program is close tho. Just a little adjustment and you're right where you need to be – take note of how the indentation makes it easy to see `if`'s 3 operands.

```
(define (last mylist)
  (if (null? mylist)
      #f
      (if (null? (cdr mylist))
          (car mylist)
          (last (cdr mylist)))))
```

Lastly, Scheme offers `cond` that helps prevent unnecessary code nesting for sequences of conditions

```
(define (last mylist)
  (cond ((null? mylist)
         #f)
        ((null? (cdr mylist))
         (car mylist))
        (else
         (last (cdr mylist)))))

(last '())
;; #f

(last '(1))
;; 1

(last '(1 2))
;; 2

(last '(1 2 3))
;; 3
```

Beyond the scope of this answer is the return value `#f` for `(last '())` – I would argue that calling `last` on an empty list should have the same effect of calling `car` on an empty list. But I'll leave it up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If `(null? mylist)` does not hold, what is it? A non-empty list.

Non-empty lists may have one, or more, elements.

How many elements have such lists that their last element is their first?

What can be said about such lists' `cdr`? You should use this to stop your recursion earlier. Right now it continues until the list is empty, but you need to stop earlier than that.

```
(define (last mylist)
      (if (list? mylist)
              (if (null? mylist)
                  '()
                  ;; {1}
                  (last (cdr mylist))
                  ;;
                  )))
```

at `{1}` you call `(last (cdr mylist))` unconditionally. But what if you've reached the end of your list? What if only one element is left? You'll need to return *it* as the result, in such case. So, replace the unconditional code with an `if` expression to accomplish this.

Comment: I understand why I'm getting the empty list, I'm just not sure how to fix it. We were given a very small subset of the language to work with.

Comment: it will return the first and only element of the list

Comment: good, and that will be your answer - the last element. just write down an example: given `(3 2 1)`, what will `(null? lst)` return? what will `(cdr lst)` return? do we want to proceed with that result? same for `(2 1)`. then for `(1)`. which will give you the result.

Comment: I would need a car of the list with only one element, but I'm just not sure syntax-wise where that goes

Comment: you need to add another condition that checks the cdr of your list.

Answer (score 1):

When you asked the question `(null? (cdr mylist))`, you should have returned `(car mylist)` if that's true instead of `'()`. Since at that point it means that `mylist` is a single-atom list.

```
(define (last mylist)
  (cond ((null? mylist) '())
        ((null? (cdr mylist)) (car mylist))
        (else (last (cdr mylist)))))
```

You could use `cond` instead of `if` to avoid nested conditions, since `cond` handle many arms while `if` is often used for when you have only two options for a condition.

This book [the Little Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer) did best at helping me visualize what's going on in a Scheme program.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes closest to your initial code:

```
(define (last mylist)
  (if (list? mylist)
      (if (null? mylist)
          '() ; input list is empty
          (if (null? (cdr mylist))
              (car mylist) ; list only has one remaining element so this is it
              (last (cdr mylist)))) ; otherwise, recurse
      #f)) ; input is not a list
```

When using `if`, be sure to always fill out both the *true* and the *false* branches.